# Finding the shortest route to visit every node in an undirected, unweighted graph

Tags: graph, routes, complexity-theory

Is finding the shortest route that visits every node in an undirected, unweighted graph an NP-Hard problem?

I could not find a definite answer on this one. I know that finding the shortest route that visits every node for a weighted graph is an NP-Hard problem (travelling salesman). But what about an unweighted graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there was an Algorithm ***A*** to find the shortest path connecting all nodes in an undirected, unweighted graph *G = (V, E)* in polynomial time. We will show that we could then use ***A*** to solve the *[Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)* in polynomial time, using the following steps:

1. Use ***A*** to obtain the shortest path *p* connecting all nodes *V*
2. Count the number of nodes that *p* contains; Let *k* be that node count
3. Let *n = |V|*; *G* contains a *[Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)* if and only if *k = n* (see below for a proof)

However, since the Hamilton path problem is NP-Complete such an algorithm ***A*** cannot exist, unless *P = NP*. Therefore the problem described by you must be NP-Hard.

---

**Proof that *k = n* ⇔ *G* contains a hamiltonian path**

Notice that *n ≤ k*, since *p* contains each node in *V*.

**⇒**: Suppose *k = n*. Since *p* connects *all* nodes, no node can be visited more than once. Consequently *G* contains a hamiltonian path, namely *p*.

**⇐**: Suppose *G* contains a hamiltonian path. Assume *k ≠ n*, i.e. *k > n*.
 ***A*** would then not have returned the shortest path fulfilling our requirements, since a hamiltonian path with *n* nodes exists. Consequently, it must hold that *k = n*.

∎

Comment: I don't follow. Why could we use A for solving the hamiltionian path problem?

Comment: @IonIonascu I expanded the proof. Can you follow me now?

Comment: I think i got it. So what you say is: If a graph **_G_** contains a Hamiltonian path, then the algorithm **A** should return **THAT** path. And we know this can't be done in polynomial time. Did i get it right?

Comment: @IonIonascu Yes, that is the core idea of the proof. The rest is details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time sir! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Accepted and upvoted 2 years later. Sorry I did not have the required privileges to upvote 2 years ago. Thank you again for the proof!